# PHP Client Websockets Asynchronous with SSL Encryption

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

Please guide me in the Client and server websocket connections with SSL encyption + asynchronous.

Let me know is there any way to do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

:help: :help:

Hi for supportive, i did the following code spec but some how its not working as per the requirement.

Socket client connection :

```
<?php

//Details of server websocket SSL encypted 
$ip="111.111.0.111";               //Set the TCP IP Address to connect too
$port="7109";                  //Set the TCP PORT to connect too

#Connect to Server
$socket = stream_socket_client("tcp://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, 30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT);

if($socket) {
   #Start SSL
   stream_set_blocking ($socket, true);
   stream_socket_enable_crypto ($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT);   
   stream_set_blocking ($socket, false);

   $buf = null;
   #Receive response from server. Loop until the response is finished
   while (!feof($socket)) {
      $buf .= fread($socket, 4);
   }

   #echo our command response
   echo $buf;

   #close connection
   fclose($socket);
}
?>
```

I am using `STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT` option in stream_socket_client function.The error comes is as follows

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [function.stream-socket-enable-crypto]: 
SSL: The operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: Sir, I am getting error when i am using STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT option  in stream_socket_client function.The error comes is as follows :-Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [function.stream-socket-enable-crypto]: SSL: The operation completed successfully.

Comment: Actually i want to send and receive data from server on SSL using sockets in php.So please provide some code or example regarding it

Comment: It says here that the operation completed successfully.

Comment: Yes, but the data which technically should be send from the server is not being able to receive at client end. The response data is not getting displayed as and when the server is returning the data.